# can't get full text from image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

let us suppose we have following image :
[image]

i want to extract  whole text from the image, if  i  apply thresholding like this :

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
book =cv2.imread("Book.jpg")
edges = cv2.Canny(book,220,200)
cv2.imshow("edges",edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i will get following result :

[image]

from the image  we  might think that extracting text will be easy, therefore i applied following code :

```
file = open("recognized.txt", "a")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(edges)
file.write(text)
file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

when i  run the code, i got following result in recognized.txt file

```
CO}

OO
Ue

Ha

A PROVEN SYSTEM
IN NAMING YOUR BOOK

BY BOOR PUBLICIST

SCOTT LORENZ
```

it means  , that somehow some characters  might seems unrecognizable, how  to fix it? i changed many parameters inside  canny algorithm, maybe  i should use sobel? what would be your recommendation?

Comment: Threshold your original. Then use Canny edges. Invert so edges are black on white background.  Try that.

Comment: _don't_ use canny. OCR wants solid letters. I'm glad you figured that solution out already. -- I would also wonder whether thresholding is necessary. the result of your threshold isn't binarized as such, the individual channels are binarized, so it's still a color image. tesseract seems to do its own processing.

Comment: as you see Generator is  still missing

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I removed canny algorithm and just try the threshold, here is the full solution :

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
book =cv2.imread("Book.jpg")
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(book,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# edges = cv2.Canny(thresh1,40,200)
file = open("recognized.txt", "a")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1)
file.write(text)
file.write("\n")
file.close()
# cv2.imshow("edges",edges)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

corresponding output in file is :

```
BOOK
TITLE

A PROVEN SYSTEM
IN NAMING YOUR BOOK
BY BOOK PUBLICIST

SCOTT LORENZ
```

also show  output image :
[image]